# Which is the full emoji list that I can use with `rmarkdown`?

Tags: emoji

I would like to know which is the full list of emojis which I can use with `rmarkdown`. I tried to use country flags emojis, but they only show the abbreviated form of the respective country. I also would like to use [this](https://github.githubassets.com/images/icons/emoji/shipit.png) emoji from [this list](https://github.com/swharden/code-notes/blob/master/Csharp/emoji.md), but I don't know how...

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can use the emojis from [this comprehensive list](https://github.com/hadley/emo), like this, for example:

```
`r emo::ji("france")`
```

However, you are right: it seems like many of the country/flag emoji are not displaying correctly at the moment. I have submitted this [as a GitHub issue](https://github.com/hadley/emo/issues/59).

Comment: Yes, the problem stills the same. :/

Comment: If you look at the GitHub issue (now closed) you'll see why: it's an issue with Windows support for flags as a way of representing country codes. It took me a while to work it out. I don't think there's any way round it.